# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS: Problem with drivers after upgrade to 5.11.0.38+ kernel

Tags: drivers, upgrade, kernel

I have a Gigabyte AB350M-DS3H V2-CF based system with F41 firmware + AMD Ryzen 5 2600X
With 5.11.0.37 kernel is everything greate, but after further upgrade to 5.11.0.38+ kernel there is no sound, no network at all (didn't check more)
I am newbie in linux. So could you please tell me, how can I fix it?

Somehow, can't say hello in first line. So hello, everyone! =))

Comment: 1) Revert to the older kernel at the GRUB prompt. 2) File a bug report against the `linux` package so to reversion can be identified and fixed. 3) If a bug triager responds to the bug report asking for additional information, or for you to try something, do so.